# Flutter, single streamprovider shared between multiple widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 widgets `ProfitDisplay()` and `BetListDisplay()`, I want to be able to share data from a firestore query without calling the same query twice. For `ProfitDisplay()` I'll need at least 1 more stream. My current code queries the db twice once for each widget which is not very efficient. I tried wrapping `ListView()` with `StreamProvider.value()` but then I got an error saying it could not find the Provider.
The query is based on dates selected in the first widget in the `ListView()`

```
class DailyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DailyPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DailyPageState createState() => _DailyPageState();
}

class _DailyPageState extends State<DailyPage> {
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final days = getWeekDayList;
  int _currentWeekDayNameAndNum = getCurrentWeekDayInt();

  final db = FirestoreService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int selectedDay = int.parse(days[_currentWeekDayNameAndNum]['day']);
    final User? user = auth.currentUser;
    DateTime startDate = DateTime(now.year, now.month, selectedDay, 00, 00);
    DateTime endDate = DateTime(now.year, now.month, selectedDay, 23, 59);

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: white.withOpacity(1),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: white, boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 4,
                      blurRadius: 5,
                      // changes position of shadow
                    ),
                  ]),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10, right: 10, left: 10, bottom: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: const [
                            Text(
                              "Daily Transactions",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: black),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 25,
                        ),
                        Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: List.generate(days.length, (index) {
                              return GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _currentWeekDayNameAndNum = index;
                                  });
                                },
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width:
                                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40) /
                                          7,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        days[index]['label'],
                                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(
                                        height: 10,
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        width: 30,
                                        height: 30,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: _currentWeekDayNameAndNum ==
                                                    index
                                                ? primary
                                                : Colors.transparent,
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                            border: Border.all(
                                                color:
                                                    _currentWeekDayNameAndNum ==
                                                            index
                                                        ? primary
                                                        : black
                                                            .withOpacity(0.1))),
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                            days[index]['day'],
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 10,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                color:
                                                    _currentWeekDayNameAndNum ==
                                                            index
                                                        ? white
                                                        : black),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            StreamProvider<List<BetData>>.value(
              value: FirestoreService()
                  .streamBetDataBetweenDates(user!, startDate, endDate),
              initialData: [],
              child: const ProfitDisplay(),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            StreamProvider<List<BetData>>.value(
              value: FirestoreService()
                  .streamBetDataBetweenDates(user, startDate, endDate),
              initialData: [],
              child: const BetListDisplay(),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class _ProfitDisplayState extends State<ProfitDisplay> {
  double _dailyTotal = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List betList = Provider.of<List<BetData>>(context);
    double _total = 0;
    for (var bet in betList) {
      _total += bet.value;
    }
    _dailyTotal = _total;
    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: white, boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: grey.withOpacity(0.5),
            spreadRadius: 4,
            blurRadius: 5,
            // changes position of shadow
          ),
        ]),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: _dailyTotal > 0
              ? Text(
                  '£ ${_dailyTotal.toString()}',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )
              : Text(
                  '£ ${_dailyTotal.toString()}',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Not sure if it's relevant but here's `FirestoreService()`

```
class FirestoreService {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  /// List of bets between startDate and endData
  Stream<List<BetData>> streamBetDataBetweenDates(
      User user, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    var ref = _db
        .collection('users/${user.uid}/bets')
        .where('d', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDate)
        .where('d', isLessThanOrEqualTo: endDate)
        .orderBy('d', descending: true);
    print('this got called at ${DateTime.now()}');
    return ref.snapshots().map(
        (list) => list.docs.map((doc) => BetData.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using one `StreamProvider`, and adding the two childs in a `Column` to it?

Comment: Yes, but since I will need at least one more `StreamProvider` for `ProfitDisplay` it's going to look really ugly. I was hoping there's some elegant solution for it.

Comment: And what if you use a `MultiProvider` with the two `StreamProviders`, and wrap your childs to `Consumers`? It is also possible to create `Consumer` for more than one provider.